# SPSS loop ROC analysis for lots of variables

Tags: loops, statistics, spss, roc

In SPSS, I would like to perform ROC analysis for lots of variables (989). The problem, when selecting all variables, it gives me the AUC values and the curves, but a case is immediately excluded if it has one missing value within any of the 989 variables. So, I was thinking of having a single-variable ROC analysis put into loop. But I don't have any idea how to do so. I already named all the variables var1, var2, var3, ..., var988, var989.

So, how could I loop a ROC analysis? (Checking "Treat user-missing values as valid" doesn't do the trick)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sounds like a job for python. Its usually the best solution for this sort of job in SPSS.

So heres a framwork that might help you. I am woefully unfamiliar with ROC-Analysis, but this general pattern is applicable to all kinds of looping scenarios:

```
begin program. 
import spss

for i in range(spss.GetVariableCount()): 
    var = spss.GetVariableName(i)
    cmd = r'''
* your variable-wise analysis goes here --> use spss syntax, beetween the three ' no     
* indentation is needed. since I dont know what your syntax looks like, we'll just 
* run descriptives and frequencies for all your variables as an example
descriptives %(var)s
/sta mean stddev min max. 
fre %(var)s. 
'''%locals()
    spss.Submit(cmd)
end program.
```

Just to quickly go over what this does: In line 4 we tell spss to do the following as many times as theres variables in the active dataset, 989 in your case. In line 5 we define a (python) variable named var which contains the variable name of the variable at index i (0 to 988 -  the first variable in the dataset having index 0). Then we define a command for spss to execute. I like to put it in raw strings because that simplifies things like giving directories. A raw string is defined by the r''' and ends at the '''. in line 12. "spss.Submit(cmd)" gives the command defined after "cmd = " to spss for execution. Most importantly though, whenever the name of the variable would appear in your syntax, substitute it with "%(var)s"

If you put "set mprint on." a line above the "begin program." youll see exactly what it does in the viewer.

Comment: Ja wunderbar! It works! Thank you very much for this workaround!